# Why I got exception when added a GooglePlay review in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play

Help!

I added **Google Play review** in my project, but got an exception (*screenshot attached*).

I've done it in my previous project and it was **OK**.

I've already try to add

```
-keep class com.google.android.play.core.review.** { *;}
```

to **proguard** but nothing changed(

[image: Screenshot]

Tried to fix proguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found solution, just write in proguard **this** except previous

```
-keep class com.google.android.play.core.** { *; }
```